# 2 Diffrent bat files interfer with eachothers in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I have a software that need to protect on offline machines.
My problem is as the following
1-after some procedures to check whether the machine that running my app have a license or not, if not then the app delete itself by this code

```
Private Sub SelfDestruct()

     Dim procDestruct As Process = New Process()

     Dim strName As String = "destruct.bat"

     Dim strPath As String = Path.Combine _
      (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), strName)
     Dim strExe As String = New _
      FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath).Name
     Dim swDestruct As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strPath)

     swDestruct.WriteLine("attrib """ & strExe & """" &
      " -a -s -r -h")
     swDestruct.WriteLine(":Repeat")
     swDestruct.WriteLine("del " & """" & strExe & """")
     swDestruct.WriteLine("if exist """ & strExe & """" &
      " goto Repeat")
     swDestruct.WriteLine("del """ & strName & """")

     swDestruct.Close()

     procDestruct.StartInfo.FileName = "destruct.bat"
     procDestruct.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
     procDestruct.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

     Try

         procDestruct.Start()

     Catch ex As Exception

         Close()

     End Try

 End Sub
```

It worked just fine for 4 years until I found that I need to add another method to change Machine name and the only way the worked and actually changed the name is but doing it from a bat file too.(here come the conflict)

```
Private Sub PCRename()
        
     Dim Renameact As Process = New Process()
     Dim newname As String = "rename.bat"
     Dim strName As String = "rename.bat"

     Dim strPath As String = Path.Combine _
      (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), strName)
     Dim Renametext As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strPath)
     Dim rename As String = "wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name="
     Dim source As New System.Text.StringBuilder
     Renametext.WriteLine("@echo off")
     Renametext.WriteLine(rename + """" + newname  + """")
     Renametext.WriteLine("shutdown /r -t 10")
     Renametext.WriteLine("del """ & strName & """")

     Renametext.Close()

     Renameact.StartInfo.FileName = "rename.bat"
     Renameact.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
     Renameact.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
     MessageBox.Show("Computer will restart to complete the setup", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
     Try

         Renameact.Start()
         Application.ExitThread()
         Application.Exit()

     Catch ex As Exception

         Close()

     End Try
 End Sub
```

Now each time the name change the app delete itself even if I didn't call "SelfDestruct"

I tried the code but after comment the full code for "SelfDestruct" and the app didn't delete itself when I uncomment the "SelfDestruct" and test it the problem back again and the app still delete itself.

I googled every where for 2 days but with no luck.

is there a way to separate the methods or clean StreamWriter maybe(I tried Flush() & Dispose(), still didn't work).

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your `SelfDestruct()` called - not in some `unload` type event, I hope?

Comment: Start form Load event but only under a specific conditions.

Comment: Can't you use debugger and some meaningful breakpoints? This way you should see, where your destruct is called; I suspect touching some GUI component of your app after you have almost unloaded it - this may invoke loading it again.

Comment: I only can test this action on a test machine with no VS to use, I make msgbox after each line to debug it on this test machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this finally I delete the following line from the rename method

```
 Renametext.WriteLine("del """ & strName & """")
```

then add this line after calling the method

```
Exit Sub
```

Then used this code to delete the rename.bat file on the next launch

```
Dim Filenames As String = "rename.bat"
    Dim FilePath As String = "" & AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "" & Filenames & ""
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For Some reason this line is what cuase my app to get deleted

```
Renametext.WriteLine("del """ & strName & """")
```

when I delete it the app stay but also rename.bat file and I want to delete it so no one start the bat file by mistake.